# Location of Cpanel passwords?

Tags: cpanel, hash

As we know,in cpanel, the password of emails storing in shadow file like this

```
user1:$THE_HASH_OF_USER_1:16283::::::
```

but what about the CPanel password? for example in this case we have user1 and in etc folder we can find the specific shadow just for email not for cpanel

```
/home/user1/etc/domain.com/shadow
```

by default the port number of cpanel is `2082`

Answer (score 2):

On a cPanel installed server, the entry for cPanel password is made in /etc/shadow file itself. Whenever a cPanel user is created, a user is added on your Linux server. So, every entry for the password is made in /etc/shadow file for every cPanel user you create.